# How can I align images in side columns to text in the middle column without overlap?

Tags: html, css, image, css-float, overlap

[image: How it currentl renders]I downloaded some book and magazine covers and want to use them in the margins of some filk I wrote. I want the verses to be centered, with left and right margins large enough to contain the covers relating to each verse, to be aligned to the left or right of it, except when it needs to be shifted to avoid overlap, even on old browsers. I have separate IMG classes for left and right margins. Also, I'd like the document to be responsive to changes in window size. The workaround is to insert `<br>` tags  to force the F&SF cover down enough to not overlap.

[image: With br bypass]

I could probably put the images inside of a vertically stacked  tag, but then I would lose the ability to align selected images with the appropriate lines of text. I'd like to learn something more modern, but I've seen warnings that flexbox is not supported by all browsers. In particular, I'm concerned about a really old Firefox.

I tried changing position in the style for left-side images, class L. With RELATIVE, some images shrank and displayed to the right of other images. With FIXED, the images disappeared entirely.

I expected the images to align vertically without overlap.

```css
h1 {
  font-size:4em
  text-align-center;
}
.text {
  position:absolute;
  left:20%;
  width:60%;    
}

.verse {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 60%
}

img.l {
  float: left;
  width: 12%;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20%;
}

img.r {
  float: right;
  width: 12%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class=text>
  <H1>My favorite things</H1>

  <p>
    [Verse]
  </p>
  <img class=L src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/db/Silmarillion.png" alt="The Silmarillion">
  <img class=R src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/8e/The_Fellowship_of_the_Ring_cover.gif" alt="The Fellowship of the Ring">
  <p class="verse">
    <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ungoliant">Gardening spiders</a>
    <br> And <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-earth_weapons_and_armour#Narsil">swords that are broken</a>
    <br> Words in the <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Speech">Black Speech</a>
    <br> That must not be spoken
    <br>
    <img class=L src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/11/The_Return_of_the_King_cover.gif" alt="The Return of the King">
    <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denethor">Unfaithful stewards</a>
    <br> Who don't want their kings
    <br> These are a few of my favorite things.
  </p>
  <br>
  <p>
    [hook]
  </p>
  <p class="verse">
    <img class=L src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f0/Currents_of_space.jpg" alt="The Currents of Space"> When the <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orc">orc</a> bites, when the <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Currents_of_Space">probe</a>    stings
    <br> When I'm feeling bad
    <br> I simply remember my favorite <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aragorn">kings</a>
    <br> And I don't feel so bad.
  </p>
  <p>
    [Verse]
    <img class=L src="http://www.philsp.com/visco/Magazines/ASF/ASF_0224.jpg" alt="Astounding Science Fiction vol. XLIII, no. 5, July 1949">
    <img class=R src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/38/Agent_of_vega.jpg" Alt="<i>Agent of Vega</i> front cover">
  </p>
  <p class="verse">
    Pedllers who drive their
    <br> Mysteriuos wagons
    <br> Pretty young ladies
    <br> Who can speak to dragons
    <br>
    <img class=L src="https://www.isfdb.org/wiki/images/4/45/ANLGOCT67.jpg" Alt="<i>Analog vol. 80,no 2, October 1967">
    <img class=R src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/75/AnneMcCaffrey_Dragonflight.jpg" Alt="<i>Dragonflight</i> front cover">
    <!--
                  http://www.philsp.com/visco/Magazines/ASF/ASF_0445.jpg
                  Analog vol. LXXX, no. 4, December 1967
                  Dragonrider part 1
             -->
    Travelling the Cosmos
    <br> In a
    <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ship_Who_Sang">ship who sings</a>
    <br> These are a few of my favorite things.
  </p>
  <br>
  <img class=L src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/60/ShipWhoSang.jpg" alt="<i>The Ship Who Sang</i> front cover">
  <p>
    [Verse]
  </p>
  <p class="verse">
    <img class=L src="https://www.isfdb.org/wiki/images/b/b1/FSFMar1959.jpg" alt="The Magazine of Fantasy & Science Fiction, March 1959">
    <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_You_Zombies">
Time traveling bar men
</a>
    <br> Who are like no others
    <br> Who are their own fathers
    <br> And are their own mothers
    <br>
    <img class=R src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/Heinlein-face.jpg" alt="Robert Anson Heinlein, Grand Master of SF"> Of all such stories
    <br> Know <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_A._Heinlein">Heinlein's</a> are kings
    <br> These are a few of my favorite things.
  </p>
  <br>
  <p>
    [Verse]
  </p>
  <p class="verse">
    <img class=L src="https://isfdb.org/wiki/images/1/10/LRDDRCRWLR2002.jpg" alt="Lord Darcy"> A <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_Darcy_(character)">ducal detective</a> whose
    <br> Aide does the magic
    <br> finds that their cases
    <br> are often quite tragic
    <br> I hope more stories
    <br> still lurk in the wings
    <br> These are a few of my favorite things.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: The browser currently available on ArcaOS is  Firefox ESR 45.9.0;I'm stuck with it until the next release. What more modern techniques do you suggest reading up on?

Comment: Your ask is a bit complex for CSS. It really calls for scripting to handle the overlap situation and avoid gaps in the center column text. I'm not sure it's feasible.

Comment: What about absolute positioning with potential overlap, but show the partially covered image on hover?

Comment: What is exactly you want? Can you upload a edited screenshot of you desire?

Comment: I uploaded a screen shot of the behavior prior to adding the <br> tags. Should I also add a screen shot of the behavior with the workaround?

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat of a hack, in that it still requires some manual adjustment, but it's better than futzing around with <br> tags. If I make the <img> tags block and wrap them in an inline container, then I can get the appearance I want.

BTW, I took a brief look at flexbox and grid; I didn't see an obvious way to use them for this purpose. Could you clarify? Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <TITLE>favorite things</TITLE>
        <META name="KEYWORDS" CONTENT="filk">
        <style>
            .verse {text-align: center; font-size: 2em; width:60%}
            div.l,span.l {
                     display:inline;
                     float:left;
                     width:15%;
                     position:absolute;
                     left:-20%;
                   }
            div.r,span.r {
                     display:inline;
                     float:right;
                     width:15%;
                     position:absolute;
                     right:20%;
                   }
            img.l  {
                     float:left;
                     width:999px;
                     max-width:15%;
                     position:absolute
                     left:-20%;
                   }
            img.r  {
                     float:right;
                     width:15%;
                     position:absolute;
                     right:20%;
                   }
            img.v  {
                     display:block;
                     margin:10% 10% 10% 10%;
                     width:100%;
                   }
        </style>
</head>
<BODY LANG="en-US" DIR="LTR">
<div style="position:absolute; left:20%; width:60%;">
<H1 align=center style="font-size:4em;">My favorite things</H1>

<p>
[Verse]
</p>
<div class=L>
<img class=V src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/db/Silmarillion.png"
             alt="The Silmarillion">
<img class=V src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/11/The_Return_of_the_King_cover.gif"
             alt="The Return of the King">
<img class=V src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f0/Currents_of_space.jpg"
             alt="The Currents of Space">
</div>
<div class=R>
<img class=V src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/8e/The_Fellowship_of_the_Ring_cover.gif"
             alt="The Fellowship of the Ring">
</div>
<p class="verse">
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ungoliant">Gardening spiders</a>
<br>
And <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-earth_weapons_and_armour#Narsil">swords that are broken</a>
<br>
Words in the <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Speech">Black Speech</a>
<br>
That must not be spoken
<br>
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denethor">Unfaithful stewards</a>
<br>
Who don't want their kings
<br>
These are a few of
<br>
My favorite things.
</p>
<br>
<p>
[hook]
</p>
<p class="verse">
When the <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orc">orc</a> bites,
<br>
When the <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Currents_of_Space">probe</a> stings
<br>
When I'm feeling bad
<br>
I simply remember
<br>
My favorite <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aragorn">kings</a>
<br>
And I don't feel so bad.
</p>
<p>
[Verse]
</p>
<div class=L>
<img class=V src="http://www.philsp.com/visco/Magazines/ASF/ASF_0224.jpg"
             alt="Astounding Science Fiction vol. XLIII, no. 5, July 1949">
<img class=V src="https://www.isfdb.org/wiki/images/4/45/ANLGOCT67.jpg"
             Alt="<i>Analog vol. 80,no 2, October 1967">
<img class=V src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/60/ShipWhoSang.jpg"
             alt="<i>The Ship Who Sang</i> front cover">
<img class=V src="https://www.isfdb.org/wiki/images/b/b1/FSFMar1959.jpg"
             alt="The Magazine of Fantasy & Science Fiction, March 1959">
<img class=V src="https://isfdb.org/wiki/images/1/10/LRDDRCRWLR2002.jpg"
             alt="Lord Darcy">
</div>
<div class=R>
<img class=V src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/38/Agent_of_vega.jpg"
             Alt="<i>Agent of Vega</i> front cover">
<img class=V src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/75/AnneMcCaffrey_Dragonflight.jpg"
             Alt="<i>Dragonflight</i> front cover">
             <!--
                  http://www.philsp.com/visco/Magazines/ASF/ASF_0445.jpg
                  Analog vol. LXXX, no. 4, December 1967
                  Dragonrider part 1
             -->
</div>
<p class="verse">
Peddlers who drive their
<br>
Mysteriuos wagons
<br>
Pretty young ladies
<br>
Who can speak to dragons
<br>
Travelling the Cosmos
<br>
In a
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ship_Who_Sang">ship who sings</a>
<br>
These are a few of
<br>
My favorite things.
</p>
<br>
<p>
[Verse]
</p>
<p class="verse">
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_You_Zombies">
Time traveling bar men
</a>
<br>
Who are like no others
<br>
Who are their own fathers
<br>
And are their own mothers
<br>
<span class=R>
<img class=V src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/Heinlein-face.jpg"
             alt="Robert Anson Heinlein, Grand Master of SF">
</span>
Of all such stories
<br>
Know <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_A._Heinlein">Heinlein's</a> are kings
<br>
</p>
<br>
<p>
[Verse]
</p>
<p class="verse">
A <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_Darcy_(character)">ducal detective</a> whose
<br>
Aide does the magic
<br>
finds that their cases
<br>
are often quite tragic
<br>
I hope more stories
<br>
still lurk in the wings
<br>
These are a few of
<br>
My favorite things.
</p>
</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```